# Find method of Generic List to search specific Day of Week

Tags: c#, list, generics, find

I have a `Generic List` of CallDay objects and each CallDay object has `DayOfWeek List`  I want to find if `DayOfWeek` list contains a specific day. Here is my c# code

```
public class CallDays
{
    public CallDays();


    public List<DayOfWeek> DayOWList { get; set; }
    public bool EveryDayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public bool PublicHoliday { get; set; }
}



private void IdentifyDay(List<CallDays> callDayList)
{
    // Some condition to set DayOFWeek filter criteria

    DayOfWeek dayOfWeekToFind = drInMemory.Start.DayOfWeek;

    foreach (var item in CallDayList)
    {
        // Here I need to find whether item.DayOWList contains DayOfWeek which matches dayOfWeekToFind 
        item.DayOWList.Find
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question seems very specific to your implementation. What are you really trying to do? I assume that ultimately, you're trying to filter your list of `CallDay` objects. In which case... Would `myCallDayList.Where(callDayItem => callDayItem.DayOWList.Any(day => day==dayOfWeekToFind))` do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Linq` to find by the first element that contains it. So, use the method `FirstOrDefault` and on the expression to find it, you can check if there is an `DayOfWeek` object in the `DayOWList` collection, for sample:

```
private void IdentifyDay(List<CallDays> callDayList)
{
    // Some condition to set DayOFWeek filter criteria

    DayOfWeek dayOfWeekToFind = drInMemory.Start.DayOfWeek;

    // find a object that contains the dayOfWeekToFind on the DayOWList collection
    CallDays result = CallDayList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DayOWList.Any(d => d == dayOfWeekToFind));


    // you can use the result object here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do something with the all of the CallDays objects based on whether the object's DayOWList contains the dayOfWeekToFind, you can do something like this:

```
private void IdentifyDay(List<CallDays> callDayList)
{
    // Some condition to set DayOFWeek filter criteria

    DayOfWeek dayOfWeekToFind = drInMemory.Start.DayOfWeek;

    foreach (var item in callDayList)
    {
        if (item.DayOWList.Contains(dayOfWeekToFind))
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can also do:

```
private void IdentifyDay(List<CallDays> callDayList)
{
    // Some condition to set DayOFWeek filter criteria

    DayOfWeek dayOfWeekToFind = drInMemory.Start.DayOfWeek;

    foreach (var item in CallDayList.Where(x => x.DayOWList.Contains(dayOfWeekToFind)))
    {
        // do something with the item
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This also works but I think linq is more efficient and i have replaced my code with linq lambda to avoid for each loop iteration for every callday object.

Comment: @waqas Glad to hear that was the right answer for what you were trying to do. This code is more for doing something with **every** callDayList item which passes the condition, rather than getting the first one.